# Does every node execute contracts in Proof of Stake? If yes, why?

Tags: proof-of-stake, proof-of-work

In Ethereum, for Proof of Work this sentence is true:

"*Every single operation that is executed inside the EVM is actually simultaneously executed by every node in the network. This is why gas exists*"

Is that true for Proof of Stake? I think yes is the answer as well. Then why is this needed for PofS?